# Exporting text to KML file

Tags: export, geographics

My question is "how do you export text to KML?"

Exporting Lines is straightforward. For example, the following grid was created by a function:

```
gridKML = {Line[{{{17.775776`, 59.517567`}, {17.775776`, 
       59.522055165644616`}}, {{17.777542459788478`, 
       59.51756698807526`}, {17.777542694492997`, 
       59.52205515371775`}}, {{17.779308919574486`, 
       59.51756695230104`}, {17.779309388983457`, 
       59.52205511793715`}}, {{17.78107537935547`, 
       59.51756689267733`}, {17.781076083468943`, 
       59.52205505830282`}}, {{17.782841839129`, 
       59.51756680920415`}, {17.782842777946975`, 
       59.52205497481476`}}, {{17.784608298892525`, 
       59.51756670188148`}, {17.784609472414996`, 
       59.522054867472946`}}, {{17.7863747586436`, 
       59.517566570709334`}, {17.786376166870518`, 
       59.52205473627742`}}, {{17.788141218379725`, 
       59.5175664156877`}, {17.788142861311123`, 
       59.522054581228154`}}, {{17.789907678098395`, 
       59.5175662368166`}, {17.78990955573422`, 
       59.52205440232516`}}, {{17.791674137797116`, 
       59.517566034096006`}, {17.79167625013738`, 
       59.52205419956842`}}, {{17.793440597473356`, 
       59.51756580752594`}, {17.793442944518063`, 
       59.52205397295796`}}}], 
   Line[{{{17.775776`, 59.517567`}, {17.793440597473356`, 
       59.51756580752594`}}, {{17.775776`, 
       59.51846463337708`}, {17.793440597473356`, 
       59.5184634409032`}}, {{17.775776`, 
       59.51936226663008`}, {17.793440597473356`, 
       59.51936107415635`}}, {{17.775776`, 
       59.520259899759004`}, {17.793440597473356`, 
       59.520258707285464`}}, {{17.775776`, 
       59.521157532763844`}, {17.793440597473356`, 
       59.521156340290474`}}, {{17.775776`, 
       59.522055165644616`}, {17.793440597473356`, 
       59.5220539731714`}}}]}; 
Export["grid.kml", 
 "Data" -> {{"LayerName" -> "Grid", "Geometry" -> {gridKML}}}, {"KML",
   "Rules"}]
```

and creates a file that can be viewed in Google Earth
[image]

However, when I try to understand the interface/parameters to create text, I fail.

```
Export["text.kml", 
 "Data" -> {{"LayerName" -> "Grid", 
    "Placemark" -> {Text[
       "A", {17.78290100000001`, 59.51952679585495`}]}, {"KML", 
     "Rules"}}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Analogous to how you had to wrap your grid points with the `Line[]` command, the points for your placemarks seem to need to be wrapped in `Point[]`.

Try this:

```
coords = {{17.782901, 59.519526}, {17.782000, 59.519526}};
pts = Point /@ coords;
names = {"A", "B"};
Export["text.kml", 
 "Data" -> {{"LayerName" -> "Grid", "PlacemarkNames" -> names, 
    "Geometry" -> pts}}, {"KML", "Rules"}]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great! How do you remove the "pins"?

Comment: In Google Earth if I right click on the placemarks (in the tree menu) and click on properties I can click on the push pin and then select “No Icon”. If I then resave the file as a KML (not KMZ) and rename to txt, when I open it I see the IconStyle lines with icon info listed.  I can’t figure out a way to get Export to create the IcoStyle info buy t in theory the KML file could be written as a XML file with whatever fields are needed but named with the KML extension so it is associated with Google Earth.

Comment: Good idea! I will experiment with the XML file. Found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64669736/how-to-add-a-really-tiny-placemark-to-a-kml-file-to-create-heatmap

Comment: Nice!  If I edit that file and remove the href line so it just says  <Icon></Icon> then the icon goes away.